# How to replace the standard verizon fios router with a third party router?

Tags: router, linksys

How do you setup a third-party (Linksys) router to replace the Verizon FIOS router on your network?

I recently bought a Linksys WRT1900AC router to upgrade the network in my house that has Verizon Fios.

(A lot of people have asked why.. suffice to say, it's because I believe the WRT1900AC has better coverage of the house, has AC (vs only N), and has a USB and an eSata port for a Network Area Storage device.)

Comment: [Verizon FiOS - Using Your Own Router](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Verizon_FiOS_-_Using_Your_Own_Router)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This setup is about 95% do-able (all except the mobile app).  This was not tested with verizon voip phones.

**3 main changes that need to occur:**

1. Modify FIOS ONT Box to output both CoAX and Ethernet
2. Update ONT Modem to accept a new wireless router
3. Open TCP Port 4567 to allow Channel Guide

### Guide:

**How to Modify FIOS ONT Box to output both CoAX and Ethernet?**

1. Contact Verizon Customer Service.
2. Ask politely to turn on the Ethernet port on the ONT box.  (Using the online chat, this less than 10 minutes.)

**At this point, we need to setup the Linksys Router (or other third-party router).**

1. Plug it into the Verizon FIOS router in an open ethernet port.
2. Follow setup instructions.
3. The Linksys WRT1900AC failed here.  Tell it to continue.
4. Manually set the internet connection to "Automatic DHCP." (Should pick-up an address from the fios router.)
5. The Linksys router should be providing internet on the new wifi network.
6. (Optional) Convert over all devices to the new wireless network

**Update ONT Modem to accept a new wireless router**

1. Contact Verizon Customer Service
2. Request them allow a new Wirless Router to connect the ONT Modem.
3. The tech (2nd tier most likely) is able to, however they will need to call you back as your internet will drop out.
4. The tech will ask you connect your linksys router to the ONT box. (Your chat will end)
5. The tech will issue a command, and you've got internet on your Linksys Router

At this point, Internet and Fios TV will still work, however the channel guide will not be searchable and on-demand services will not work.

**Get the Channel Guide Search and On-Demand working.**

1. Plugin the Verizon Fios Actiontec router into an ethernet port on your linksys router (opposite setup than the way we started with).
2. Connect your computer directly to the actiontec router (ethernet cable).
3. (Optional) Turn off the wifi.
4. Get the IP address of the Verizon FIOS Actiontec router.
5. Connect to the Linksys Router.
6. Add a firewall rule to open TCP Port 4567 for the ActionTec router. (The Multimedia Over CoAxial (MoCA) requires this port to be open.)

### Notes

I was unable to get the Verizon FIOS mobile app working again.  It appears the Set Top Box (STB) is hard-coded to look for the Verizon FIOS default wifi settings.

I said 95% at the top, that's broken down on how I use the services:

- 80% = Internet and FIOS TV still works
- 15% = Channel Guide Search and On Demand works
- 5% = Verizon FIOS mobile app

Helpful sources I found:

- http://www.marco.org/2011/01/15/how-to-use-your-own-router-with-fios

I wasn't able to find any other comprehensive resources to help me with this, thus is why I wrote this here.  My apologies if this isn't quite the right fit for this StackExchange site, however I thought the knowledge was very much worth sharing.

Comment: I can confirm that I successfully followed these instructions to access internet through my third party router, the TL-WR841N. I did not attempt the Channel Guide Search and On-Demand since I do not have those services.

Answer (score -1):

With Frontier Fios service following instructions similar to above up to "Get Channel Guide..." got everything working including the channel guide, On Demand, AND the mobile app.

The mobile app didn't work at first but then I restarted my set-top boxes (DVR and the small non-dvr box) and the mobile app started working.  I'm using Google Wifi and the subnet 192.168.86.xxx and once I saw that the set top boxed had been assigned IP's in that sub I knew I should keep trying until it worked.